# How do I get these two functions to execute on the same script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have multiple functions on the script below, which work when I run them individually.

I am trying to make one script, that when ran, takes arrays from a spreadsheet, enters them into a template, produces the new file in my designated folder, then converts that new file into a PDF.

Each script works by itself well, but when I try to run them together, it converts the file into a PDF without the variables from the sheet in it (so essentially just creates a bunch of PDFs of the template document) but will return a document with the right variables entered.

I feel like the second function is executing before the first function has finished, but I am unsure.

```
function createDocument() {
  //To pull the headers of each column - insert spreadsheet URL and header array
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'A2:AA2');
  //To pull the variables for each header - insert spreadsheet URL and variable array
  var variables = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'A3:AA4');
  //To pull the template document for the header and variables to be input by the program
  var templateId = '1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI';

//Loop to run through all variables in spreadsheet
  for(var i = 0; i < variables.values.length; i++){
    
    //Create the variables which will be used to transfer the data from the spreadsheet to the document. The first cell in the row is 0 and then from left to right, increases in its number. Only change variable name and the number.
    var client = variables.values[i][0];
    var agent = variables.values[i][1];
    var aaddress = variables.values[i][2];
    var acity = variables.values[i][3];
    var caddress = variables.values[i][4];
    var ccity = variables.values[i][5];
    var suopen = variables.values[i][6];
    var suclose = variables.values[i][7];
    var moopen = variables.values[i][8];
    var moclose = variables.values[i][9];
    var tuopen = variables.values[i][10];
    var tuclose = variables.values[i][11];
    var weopen = variables.values[i][12];
    var weclose = variables.values[i][13];
    var thopen = variables.values[i][14];
    var thclose = variables.values[i][15];
    var fropen = variables.values[i][16];
    var frclose = variables.values[i][17];
    var saopen = variables.values[i][18];
    var saclose = variables.values[i][19];
    var price = variables.values[i][20];
    var appayment = variables.values[i][21];
    var mpayment = variables.values[i][22];
    var junepayment = variables.values[i][23];
    var julypayment = variables.values[i][24];
    var aupayment = variables.values[i][25];
    var sepayment = variables.values[i][26];
    
    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI').makeCopy().getId();
    
    //Rename the copied file
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('2022' + " " + client + " " + 'Pool Management Proposal');

    // Set copied file's destination;
    var destination_id = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);  
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('1YVhLzwZ9CI5-iTR1SKHF5ykNVqZQvQY9');
  
    // Send copied file to this folder
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
    file.moveTo(destination);
    
    //Get the document body as a variable
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
        
    //Insert Data from sheet to document. ##info## is the placeholder text in the document, and the second variable is the variable we set above to codify the column's data in the sheet.
    body.replaceText('##Agent Name##', agent);
    body.replaceText('##Agent Address##', aaddress);
    body.replaceText('##Agent City/Zip##', acity);
    body.replaceText('##Client Name##', client)
    body.replaceText('##Client Address##', caddress);
    body.replaceText('##Client City/Zip##', ccity);
    body.replaceText('##Contract Price##', price);
    body.replaceText('##April Payment##', appayment);
    body.replaceText('##May Payment##', mpayment);
    body.replaceText('##June Payment##', junepayment);
    body.replaceText('##July Payment##', julypayment);
    body.replaceText('##August Payment##', aupayment);
    body.replaceText('##September Payment##', sepayment);
    body.replaceText('##Sunday Open##', suopen);
    body.replaceText('##Sunday Close##', suclose);
    body.replaceText('##Monday Open##', moopen);
    body.replaceText('##Monday Close##', moclose);
    body.replaceText('##Tuesday Open##', tuopen);
    body.replaceText('##Tuesday Close##', tuclose);
    body.replaceText('##Wednesday Open##', weopen);
    body.replaceText('##Wednesday Close##', weclose);
    body.replaceText('##Thursday Open##', thopen);
    body.replaceText('##Thursday Close##', thclose);
    body.replaceText('##Friday Open##', fropen);
    body.replaceText('##Friday Close##', frclose);
    body.replaceText('##Saturday Open##', saopen);
    body.replaceText('##Saturday Close##', saclose);

}
}

function gdocToPDF() {
    var documentRootfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1YVhLzwZ9CI5-iTR1SKHF5ykNVqZQvQY9") // replace this with the ID of the folder that contains the documents you want to convert
    var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1_idXGdZo0l_U1IxuaLDUqrk0HjdfZvsg"); // replace this with the ID of the folder that the PDFs should be put in. 

    var documentRootFiles = documentRootfolder.getFiles()

    while(documentRootFiles.hasNext()) {
        createPDF(documentRootFiles.next().getId(), pdfFolder.getId(), function (fileID, folderID) {
            if (fileID) createPDFfile(fileID, folderID);
        })
    }

function createPDF(fileID, folderID, callback) {
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    var templateName = templateFile.getName();
    
    var existingPDFs = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).getFiles();

    //in case no files exist
    if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
        return callback(fileID, folderID);
    }

    for (; existingPDFs.hasNext();) {

        var existingPDFfile = existingPDFs.next();
        var existingPDFfileName = existingPDFfile.getName();
        if (existingPDFfileName == templateName + ".pdf") {
            Logger.log("PDF exists already. No PDF created")
            return callback();
        }
        if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
            Logger.log("PDF is created")
            return callback(fileID, folderID)
        }
    }
}

function createPDFfile(fileID, folderID) {
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
    var newPDFFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

    var fileName = templateFile.getName().replace(".", ""); //otherwise filename will be shortened after full stop    
    newPDFFile.setName(fileName + ".pdf");
}
}
```

Comment: I only see one function.

Comment: Oops... I ended up removing the second function because it would not create PDFs with it. Is there any way to make this run as one function?

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:  `var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();`

to this: ` var document = DocumentApp.openById(documentId)
var body = document.getBody();'

at the end put `document.saveAndClose()`

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, I replaced what you said, and I tired to put '''document.saveAndClose()''' at the end of the first function, but nothing. I just need the other functions to wait I think until the first function has completed.

Comment: did you try to reopen the document after the save?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
function createDoc(){
console.log("first");

  // To pull the headers of each column - insert spreadsheet URL and header array
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'A2:AA2');
  // To pull the variables for each header - insert spreadsheet URL and variable array
  var variables = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1846CxmPdoc2VBW6GxaybCPW1_u2swO1jooIBiF2Yl90', 'A3:AA14');
  // To pull the template document for the header and variables to be input by the program
  var templateId = '1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI';


  // Loop to run through all variables in spreadsheet
  for(var i = 0; i < variables.values.length; i++){
    
    // Create the variables which will be used to transfer the data from the spreadsheet to the document. The first cell in the row is 0 and then from left to right, increases in its number. Only change variable name and the number.
    var client = variables.values[i][0];
    var agent = variables.values[i][1];
    var aaddress = variables.values[i][2];
    var acity = variables.values[i][3];
    var caddress = variables.values[i][4];
    var ccity = variables.values[i][5];
    var suopen = variables.values[i][6];
    var suclose = variables.values[i][7];
    var moopen = variables.values[i][8];
    var moclose = variables.values[i][9];
    var tuopen = variables.values[i][10];
    var tuclose = variables.values[i][11];
    var weopen = variables.values[i][12];
    var weclose = variables.values[i][13];
    var thopen = variables.values[i][14];
    var thclose = variables.values[i][15];
    var fropen = variables.values[i][16];
    var frclose = variables.values[i][17];
    var saopen = variables.values[i][18];
    var saclose = variables.values[i][19];
    var price = variables.values[i][20];
    var appayment = variables.values[i][21];
    var mpayment = variables.values[i][22];
    var junepayment = variables.values[i][23];
    var julypayment = variables.values[i][24];
    var aupayment = variables.values[i][25];
    var sepayment = variables.values[i][26];
  }

  // Make a copy of the template file
  const documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1ONhT3n4Pr49BL6xEM_ykO9UVi8xZriA2fVAZjoFi2qI').makeCopy().getId();

  // Rename the copied file
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('2022' + " " + client + " " + 'Pool Management Proposal');
    
  // Set copied file's destination variable;
  var folderId = DriveApp.getFolderById('1YVhLzwZ9CI5-iTR1SKHF5ykNVqZQvQY9');
  
  // Send copied file to this folder
  var fileId = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  fileId.moveTo(folderId); 

  // Get the document body as a variable
  const  OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  const body = OpenDoc.getBody();

  // Insert Data from sheet to document. ##info## is the placeholder text in the document, and the second variable is the variable we set above to codify the column's data in the sheet.
  body.replaceText('##Agent Name##', agent);
  body.replaceText('##Agent Address##', aaddress);
  body.replaceText('##Agent City/Zip##', acity);
  body.replaceText('##Client Name##', client)
  body.replaceText('##Client Address##', caddress);
  body.replaceText('##Client City/Zip##', ccity);
  body.replaceText('##Contract Price##', price);
  body.replaceText('##April Payment##', appayment);
  body.replaceText('##May Payment##', mpayment);
  body.replaceText('##June Payment##', junepayment);
  body.replaceText('##July Payment##', julypayment);
  body.replaceText('##August Payment##', aupayment);
  body.replaceText('##September Payment##', sepayment);
  body.replaceText('##Sunday Open##', suopen);
  body.replaceText('##Sunday Close##', suclose);
  body.replaceText('##Monday Open##', moopen);
  body.replaceText('##Monday Close##', moclose);
  body.replaceText('##Tuesday Open##', tuopen);
  body.replaceText('##Tuesday Close##', tuclose);
  body.replaceText('##Wednesday Open##', weopen);
  body.replaceText('##Wednesday Close##', weclose);
  body.replaceText('##Thursday Open##', thopen);
  body.replaceText('##Thursday Close##', thclose);
  body.replaceText('##Friday Open##', fropen);
  body.replaceText('##Friday Close##', frclose);
  body.replaceText('##Saturday Open##', saopen);
  body.replaceText('##Saturday Close##', saclose);

  OpenDoc.saveAndClose();

  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1_idXGdZo0l_U1IxuaLDUqrk0HjdfZvsg"); 
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var newPDFFile = folderId.createFile(theBlob);
  newPDFFile.moveTo(pdfFolder);

   var fileName = templateFile.getName().replace(".", ""); // otherwise filename will be shortened after full stop   
  newPDFFile.setName(fileName + ".pdf").getId();
}
```